# Searching and finding or creating fields with partials and Ajax in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

Say I'm creating a book under an author, so I must pick up an existing author or create one. Well, I thought I could just have a search field; through CoffeeScript I'd have an `$.ajax()` returning a view with a table with the results and a button to choose the item. If there are no records, there'd be a link for the author's form partial. *I'm not really sure this is the best approach, though.*

The problem is that I can't pass the `f` variable to the returning view in case the user needs to fill in the form. I tried leaving the link for the form in the original view, but I wouldn't know when to trigger it through JS.

[image: Basic representation]

This is what I have now:

```html
# new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @author do |f| %>
    <%= render 'search', f: f %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

```html
# _search.html.erb
<%= text_field :author_search_name %>
<%= link_to 'Search', '#', id: 'author_search_submit',
    ajax_path: author_search_path %>

<div id="author_search_result"></div>
```

```js
# author.js.coffee
$('#author_search_result').hide
$('#author_search_submit').click (event) ->
    $.ajax
        url: $(this).attr('ajax_path'),
        params: { chassi: $('#author_search_name').val() },
        success: (data) ->
            $('#author_search_result').html(data).show
```

There's a couple of more files, but these are the most important ones. The `author_search_path` is the view with the resulting records or the warning that the form must be filled in. I'm really confused because I've been over this issue for some days and nothing seems to work. I hope this is enough to explain my problem.

**UPDATE:**

```html
# author_search.html.erb
<% if @authors.size > 0 %>
    <table>
        ...
        <% @authors.each do |author| %>
            <tr>
                ...
                <td><%= link_to "Select", '#', data_author_id: author.id %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
<% else %>
    <p>There are no authors with this name.
    You can create a new one by <%= link_to_add_fields 'clicking here', f %></p>
<% end %>
```

In the code above I have no access to the `f` variable, which can't let me render the form.

```rb
# application_helper.rb
def link_to_add_fields(name, f)
    link_to name, '#', data: { fields: render('fields', f: f).gsub("\n", "") }
end
```

```html
# _fields.html.erb
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :age %>
...
```

Is it too weird and complicated yet? I can't think of any other way for searching/finding or filling a form.

Comment: Why not just render the form along with the search field and submit and just leave it hidden until needed? Validation on the backend can prevent duplication if someone was trying to be devious and unhid the form to fill it out anyway.

Comment: If their is nothing, return back something that says there is nothing. Than in the success function check for that value. If it is there, show the form. If it is not there, you know you have your data, so show it. It would be better to do it in JSON than a string, and you should probably fill in the name since they already searched for it.

Comment: Also, it seems you're combining two functions into a single form. **1.** Searching for existing authors and **2.** Creating a new author. Whether you keep the partial or not, it seems you'd be better served wrapping the create author fields in a separate for **for creating an author** than the form designed to **search for an author**.

Comment: Oh, yes, I'm aware of the forms fusion, but since I'm using a fieldset and it's a jquery-based wizard, I must leave the search field inside the main form. And as I said, I can't pass the f variable to the new form. I updated my question with more details. Oh, could you please explain some more about the JSON part?